# Docker volume on a file inside an ear/jar/zip?

Tags: java, docker, docker-volume

i encountered a problem where i have a properties file inside an ear that is dockerized and i want to change the variables of that file during run time,

So i was wondering is it possible to make a volume to that file (volume to a position that's inside a compressed file) ?

And if no is there another solution ?

Comment: you'd have the same problem without docker. You should change the Java application to allow configuration outside of the properties file.

Answer (score 2):

If a value is supposed to change at runtime, in my opinion, it does not belong inside a .properties file, and it definitely does not belong inside your EAR.

Personally, I'd prefer to have something like that inside a database (if I have one at my disposal). You could also have a "configuration server" which your application can call via REST, but that is probably overkill. If you absolutely need to have a properties file - use one that is outside of your EAR file, and use a regular volume. An EAR is supposed to be immutable and changing it at runtime will only bring you pain.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if thats possible.. You could try to do some `docker exec -it bash` and script your way to change the file. Or as the comments suggest rewrite your app to read properties from outside of ear from specified volume, which you can easily attach to your docker image

Comment: At least some application servers actually unpack the EAR file to some internal folder (Websphere definitely does), so you could map that folder as a docker volume. It is still hacky and as I say in my answer, I would *not* recommend doing it.